# Why is Informatica email task repeating the text

Tags: email, informatica-powercenter

Why does my On-Failure/Success emails repeat their text, sometimes hundreds of times?  The problem affects email tasks both On-Success and On-Failure.

I have a session where I have an On-Failure Email to be sent.  I created a Task and am referencing it under the Components.

The email arrives, but the text of the email has been repeated, in this case 41 times.  In other emails, I have seen the text content repeated 250 times.  Ultimately, I will see an error message in the session log.

Why would the text repeat itself?

In the Task definition the email text is:

```
** %e **

Folder: %n 
Workflow: %w 

Session: %s 
Status: %e
%b 
%c

%i 

Mapping: %m

%l  
%r

%g
```

Here is the email  itself.  I am only showing a portion where you can see the repeating text blocks.  In this email, the text repeated 41 times.  The text starts with with my first line: '** Failed **'

Why?  Bug?   We use Informatica 10.0

```
** Failed **

Folder: Davidson 
Workflow: wf_m_Event_Wait_AUS 

Session: s_m_Event_Wait_AUS_bo 
Start Time: Mon Jun 26 10:25:14 2017 
Completion Time: Mon Jun 26 10:25:17 2017

Elapsed time: 0:00:02 (h:m:s) 

Mapping: m_Event_Wait_AUS_bo [version 6]

Total Rows Loaded = 0  
Total Rows Rejected = 0** Failed **

Folder: Davidson 
Workflow: wf_m_Event_Wait_AUS 

Session: s_m_Event_Wait_AUS_bo 
Start Time: Mon Jun 26 10:25:14 2017 
Completion Time: Mon Jun 26 10:25:17 2017

Elapsed time: 0:00:02 (h:m:s) 

Mapping: m_Event_Wait_AUS_bo [version 6]

Total Rows Loaded = 0  
Total Rows Rejected = 0** Failed **

Folder: Davidson 
Workflow: wf_m_Event_Wait_AUS 

Session: s_m_Event_Wait_AUS_bo 
Start Time: Mon Jun 26 10:25:14 2017 
Completion Time: Mon Jun 26 10:25:17 2017

Elapsed time: 0:00:02 (h:m:s) 

Mapping: m_Event_Wait_AUS_bo [version 6]

Total Rows Loaded = 0  
Total Rows Rejected = 0
```

Comment: Seems like some multiple execution... What's the source? How the session is invoked? It's just a long shot, but is it possible you call it multiple times like e.g. with indirect file?

Comment: Am just moving text data to SQL Server table.  Workflow: ..source (csv).....exp-tran (do nothing)...target (sql server table).    I have  task called tsk_Email_Success, and tsk_Email_Failure.  I put them in the Session On-Success-Email and On-Failure email. Seems pretty straight-forward.  Often, in addition to the text being repeated, the email address will also have my email address appended over and over also. This is a direct file, not an indirect file.  I feel like I've tried everything to get this to work.  There's just one partition, nothing fancy.

Comment: How do you prepare the message text and recipients? Is it via some variable? Do you use SETVARIABLE() function?

Comment: Everything is hard-code right into the email tasks.  I am not introducing parameter files until I have the basics working.  The actual text message is shown above.  The session populates them but also repeats them ?

Comment: A friend suggested using a non-reusable email which didn't work AT ALL... in fact, since I tried that I haven't been able to get any email now no matter what I do.

Comment: Each time I modify the email text in the session, it just appends it to the previous version as if it's in cache or something.  I had to abandon it and go to an Assignment transformer and then to an Email in the work flow.  Post-Session emails are buggy.

Comment: I presume it's not visible in Workflow Designer. Can you try exporting to XML and checking the contents? Is the email msg duplicated there as well? Do you use a versioned or non-versioned repository?

Comment: I exported the workflow and looked into the XML.  The duplicate texts were in the XML.  Something is appending them.  Also, curiously, if I Revert the text back to the original email task's text,and then I export/inspect the object's XML, I will see the email text back to normal.  But when I run the job again, it has the old text in the email.  Occasionally the email is correct--occasionally.

Comment: This sound's like a job for admins or even raising a ticket to the vendor. I give up - however I'd be really happy to get to know the root cause, if you'd ever get this one resolved.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the XML exported using Repository Manager (it's important!) somewhere?